# What is the correct declaration of a form in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am just porting a project from VB6 to VB.NET with the help of the Microsoft Upgrade Wizard.

One form was automatically upgraded to

```
Friend Partial Class frmAudFeedSentenceEdit
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

But when I add a new form to a new project in VB.NET, it is declared as

```
 Public Class frmAudFeedSentenceEdit
```

(without the Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form).

Which one is correct, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a form using Visual Studio, it will put the form information into 2 separate files.

The part you're seeing:

```
Public Class frmAudFeedSentenceEdit
```

Is just the declaration in the main file, where you will normally work.

However, there is a second file created (`frmAudFeedSentenceEdit.Designer.vb`) which will have:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class frmAudFeedSentenceEdit
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

As you can see, it's still a `Partial Class`, but the `Inherits` statement is placed in the designer-generated file for you.

You can see this if you look in the `Class View` window, browse to your form, and double click on `InitializeComponent()` (as this Sub is defined in the designer file).

Comment: @MarkJ VB is interesting this way - unlike C#, you can have a Partial class where only 1 side (the designer) is decorated as Partial, so it's not always obvious that it's a form ;)

Comment: But why did it say "Friend" when it upgraded my VB6 code? Or to be more exact: What does the "Friend" keyword do in a form?

Comment: @tmighty This is the accessibility.  By default, when you upgraded, it made it Friend.  Now things are "Public" by default (so you can use them from other assemblies).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx